# SAML2.0 mixed content error in SSO implementation

Tags: c#, .net-core, single-sign-on, mixed-content, pingfederate

I have implemented SSO using saml2.0 ping federate, the request is getting successfully but intermittently it is facing mixed content error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have followed this link for our implementation https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp